# Angular routing redirect without cutting the url

Tags: angular, routes

Currently I'm trying to create an Angular app where the user can receive a specific URL : e.g `/answer/1234d1fjs8` and whenever "answer" is in the URL the routing should open the component "answer".
I've done this with routing and redirect but sadly the app cuts out the id (1234d1fjs8) and the url after routing is simply `/answer`.
I either need to safe the part of the url after the `/answer` in a variable/service or redirect without cutting the url. I'd prefer the redirect without cutting.

Routes from app-routing.module.ts :
`{ path: 'answer', component: SummaryComponent},
 { path: 'answer',redirectTo:'/answer',pathMatch: 'prefix'}`

Comment: where have you defined the path params? you need to define path as 'answer/:id' 
and why are you defining same path twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{ path: 'answer/:id', component: SummaryComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routing you did not mentions params. so your params not getting

Change your Routing

{ path: 'answer/:id', component: SummaryComponent}